# Run procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created 3 procedures and the 3<sup>rd</sup> calls the other two:

#### pi function

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pi$$
CREATE PROCEDURE pi()
BEGIN
DECLARE pi FLOAT;
SET pi = 3.14;
SELECT pi;
END$$
```

#### power function

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pot$$
CREATE PROCEDURE pot(input_number INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE pot FLOAT; 
SET pot= input_number;
SELECT POWER (pot,2);
END$$
```

#### areac function

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS areac$$
CREATE PROCEDURE areac(input_number INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE area FLOAT;
SET area = input_number;
SELECT pi()*pot(area,2);
END$$
```

When I run `CALL areac(1)$$`, this error appears:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION aula3.pot does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The first two statements create `STORED PROCEDURE` and not `FUNCTION`. Here's the syntax to create function.

For `PI()`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION pi()
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    RETURN 3.14;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

For `POT()`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION pot(input_number INT)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    RETURN POWER(input_number, 2);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and you can now execute this statement: `CALL areac(1)`

Comment: try returning `DECIMAL(10,5)` instead of `FLOAT`.